# WordPress Backend Conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a conditional to filter upload_dir() but only if a user is on the frontend, so I don't want to filter it if the user is on the backend creating new posts or checking media uploaded to Wordpress or Uploading new media. I am currently using the is_admin() conditional but an admin user viewing the store page on the front end will not see it filtered.

The reason why I'm filtering is because the current template is using upload_dir to get products images, I know it's not recommended to use upload_dir but I can't modify this. This is my code:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', array(&$this,
    'replace_content_url'
));

public function replace_content_url($content)
{
    $old = site_url();
    $new = CDN_URL;
    if (!empty($new) && is_admin) {
        $content = str_replace($old, $new, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_admin` should work just fine because :

"Whether the current request is for an administrative interface page."

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

Comment: I actually thought that is_admin was to check if the current logged in user had admin rights, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the front-end is using AJAX to upload media then is_admin() will not work as AJAX request are executed in the WP Admin context. From https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins:

Note 2: Both front-end and back-end Ajax requests use admin-ajax.php so is_admin() will always return true in your action handling code.

However, you can use the HTTP Referer - $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - to know the page that sent the AJAX request. You should be able to determine if that page is a front-end or back-end page. Backend pages have wp-admin in their path, e.g., http://xxx.yyy.zzz/wp-admin/upload.php, http://xxx.yyy.zzz/wp-admin/post.php?post=13239&action=edit